# Python: Very slow execution loops

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, optimization

I am writing a code for proposing typo correction using HMM and Viterbi algorithm. At some point for each word in the text I have to do the following. (lets assume I have 10,000 words)

```
#FYI Windows 10, 64bit, interl i7 4GRam, Python 2.7.3
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

for k in range(10000):
    tempWord = corruptList20[k] #Temp word read form the list which has all of the words
    delta = np.zeros(26, len(tempWord)))
    sai = np.chararray(26, len(tempWord)))
    sai[:] = '@'

    # INITIALIZATION DELTA
    for i in range(26):
        delta[i][0] = #CALCULATION matrix read and multiplication each cell is different
    # INITILIZATION END

    # 6.DELTA  CALCULATION
    for deltaIndex in range(1, len(tempWord)):
        for j in range(26):
            tempDelta = 0.0
            maxDelta = 0.0
            maxState = ''
            for i in range(26):
                # CALCULATION to fill each cell involve in:
                   # 1-matrix read and multiplication
                   # 2 Finding Column Max
                   # logical operation and if-then-else operations

    # 7. SAI BACKWARD TRACKING
    delta2 = pd.DataFrame(delta)
    sai2 = pd.DataFrame(sai)

    proposedWord = np.zeros(len(tempWord), str)
    editId = 0
    for col in delta2.columns:
         # CALCULATION to fill each cell involve in:
                # 1-matrix read and multiplication
                # 2 Finding Column Max
                # logical operation and if-then-else operations
         editList20.append(''.join(editWord))
#END OF LOOP
```

As you can see it is computationally involved and When I run it takes too much time to run. 
Currently my laptop is stolen and I run this on Windows 10, 64bit, 4GRam, Python 2.7.3

My question: Anybody can see any point that I can use to optimize? Do I have to delete the the matrices I created in the loop before loop goes to next round to make memory free or is this done automatically?

[image]

After the below comments and using `xrange` instead of `range` the performance increased almost by **30%**. I am adding the screenshot here after this change.

[image]

Comment: What version of Python is this? I can't see any identifying parts. I can't remember exactly, but `range` might be constructing a list instead of just being an iterate range object.

Comment: Thanks for asking: Python 2.7.3

Comment: Look up the behavior of range in that version. I know there was a change for a range iterable from version 2 to 3.

Comment: I am just allowed to use Python2

Comment: In Python 2, using `xrange` instead of `range` avoids the need to actually construct the list before iterating.  In Python 3, `range` does what `xrange` did in Python 2.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thank you. That's what I was talking about.

Comment: @Rebin xrange creates a simple range object that consists only of 3 numbers. range constructs a list, then iterates over that, which consumes a ton of unnecessary memory.

Comment: Ok, Are you suggesting me to change to 'xrange' ?

Comment: Thanks for differentiating them, I was always having difficulty understanding the difference.

Comment: @Rebin Yes, that will eliminate the overhead of constructing and destroying a list every loop.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that. Do I have to delete the inner matrices like DELTA and SAI  before loop wants to restart?

Comment: for larger range  an alternate version can be crafted using the itertools module: islice(count(start, step), (stop-start+step-1+2*(step<0))//step)

Comment: @sb0709 I'm pretty tired, but that basically just looks like a simple range implementation. Shouldn't that be the same as xrange?

Comment: @Rebin The behavior will be exactly the same from the caller's perspective. The only difference should be how it handlers the iteration internally. You shouldn't need to change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that `range` discussion makes much difference.  With Python3, where `range` is the iterator, expanding it into a list before iteration doesn't change time much.

```
In [107]: timeit for k in range(10000):x=k+1
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.43 ms per loop

In [108]: timeit for k in list(range(10000)):x=k+1
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.58 ms per loop
```

With `numpy` and `pandas` the real key to speeding up loops is to replace them with compiled operations that work on the whole array or dataframe.  But even in pure Python, focus on streamlining the contents of the iteration, not the iteration mechanism.

======================

```
for i in range(26):
    delta[i][0] = #CALCULATION matrix read and multiplication
```

A minor change: `delta[i, 0] = ...`; this is the array way of addressing a single element; functionally it often is the same, but the intent is clearer.  But think, can't you set all of that column as once?

```
delta[:,0] = ...
```

====================

```
N = len(tempWord)
delta = np.zeros(26, N))
etc
```

In tight loops temporary variables like this can save time.  This isn't tight, so here is just adds clarity.

===========================

This one ugly nested triple loop; admittedly 26 steps isn't large, but 26*26*N is:

```
for deltaIndex in range(1,N):
    for j in range(26):
        tempDelta = 0.0
        maxDelta = 0.0
        maxState = ''
        for i in range(26):
            # CALCULATION 
               # 1-matrix read and multiplication
               # 2 Finding Column Max
               # logical operation and if-then-else operations
```

Focus on replacing this with array operations.  It's those 3 commented lines that need to be changed, not the iteration mechanism.

================

Make `proposedWord` a list rather than array might be faster.  Small list operations are often faster than array one, since `numpy` arrays have a creation overhead.

```
In [136]: timeit np.zeros(20,str)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.36 µs per loop

In [137]: timeit x=[' ']*20
1000000 loops, best of 3: 614 ns per loop
```

You have to careful when creating 'empty' lists that the elements are truly independent, not just copies of the same thing.

```
In [159]: %%timeit                      
x = np.zeros(20,str)
for i in range(20):
   x[i] = chr(65+i)
   .....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.1 µs per loop

In [160]: timeit [chr(65+i) for i in range(20)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.7 µs per loop
```

Comment: Considering the OP is using nested ranges though, any differences will compound.

Comment: Thank you, I am incorporating your comments and update the results.

Comment: but I could not mark your solution as answer, i dont know why?!!

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, the behavior of `range` changed between Python 2 and 3.

In 2, `range` constructs an entire list populated with the numbers to iterate over, *then* iterates over the list. Doing this in a tight loop is very expensive.

In 3, `range` instead constructs a simple object that (as far as I know), consists only of 3 numbers: the starting number, the step (distance between numbers), and the end number. Using simple math, you can calculate any point along the range instead of needing to iterate necessarily. This makes "random access" on it O(1) instead of O(n) when the entire list is interated, and prevents the creation of a costly list.

In 2, use `xrange` to iterate over a range object instead of a list.

(@Tom: I'll delete this if you post an answer).

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to see exactly what you need to do because of the missing code, but it's clear that you need to learn how to vectorize your numpy code.  This can lead to a 100x speedup.

You can probably get rid of all the inner for-loops and replace them with vectorized operations.

eg. instead of

```
for i in range(26):
    delta[i][0] = #CALCULATION matrix read and multiplication each cell is differen
```

do

```
delta[:, 0] = # Vectorized form of whatever operation you were going to do.
```

Comment: each element of the matrix is calculated differently so how can I verctorizing? is there any source that you can mention or any task that I can practice?

Comment: Chances are that, instead of calling whatever function you use to update each element individually, you could refactor that function so it processes inputs as batches.  (Taking and returning arrays instead of scalars).  Looping in python is slow.  The internal looping that numpy does is fast.